# Cosine Similarity between two sentences of different length using word2vec Google News Corpus in Java

Tags: java, word2vec, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I want to find Cosine Similarity between two sentences of different length using word2vec Google news corpus. This method allows me to find cosine similarity between two sentence of same length but throws error when the length is different.

```
@RestController
public class word2vecsentence {
@Autowired
Word2VecModel wordVector;


 @RequestMapping(value="/sentsimilarity",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public double cosineSimForSentence(@RequestParam("sent1") String sentence1,
 @RequestParam("sent2")String sentence2){
 Collection<String> label1 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(sentence1);
 Collection<String> label2 = Splitter.on(' ').splitToList(sentence2);

 WordVectors vector = wordVector.getModel();
 double consin = 0;
 try{
 INDArray array1 = vector.getWordVectorsMean(label1);
 System.out.println(array1);
 INDArray array2 = vector.getWordVectorsMean(label2);
 System.out.println(array2);
 consin = Transforms.cosineSim(array1, array2);
 return consin;
 }catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 return consin;
 }
 }}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @garysieling Thanks, I resolved the issue. It was in the way i was reading the pre trained model.